# Filamentphp laravel command: php artisan vendor:publish --tag=filament-actions-migrations not working, no publishable resources

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-filament, filamentphp

In Filament v3, I am attempting to import a CSV file into my database by following the documentation. However, when I run the command php artisan vendor:publish --tag=filament-actions-migrations, I encounter the following error: 'No publishable resources for tag [filament-actions-migrations].' Can you please assist?

I have followed the Filament documentation, but it seems insufficient. Could you provide a solution or suggest an alternative method for importing a CSV file into the database model?